# DigitalOcean, Docker, Dokku: Installing Firefox inside a container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I have an application which needs to use a headed browser periodically.

I want to Host it using Dokku.

How can I install this into my DO container?

When I run:

```
dokku run MY_APP apt-get install firefox
```

I get:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd-daemon0_204-5ubuntu20.9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
.
.
.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubufox/xul-ext-ubufox_2.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

After which running:

```
dokku run MY_APP firefox
```

returns:
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container ... exec: "firefox": executable file not found in $PATH

I am aware that PhatomJS is a better solution but some third party gem I am using are dependant on a headed firefox browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message you are getting when installing Firefox, it seems like your apt cache inside the Docker container is out-of-date. Running `apt-get update` first should resolve the problem.

Though to run Firefox headless, you'll need another step. You'll need to prepend your command with `xvfb-run` which is part of the `xvfb` package. It will allow you to run commands in a virtual X server environment.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.

I feel quite silly now, all of the tutorials included apt-get update but I presumed my Droplet would be up to date!